# Como integrar Spring Security 6 + React login/registro

Tags: reactjs, spring-security

estoy intentando crear un proyecto, utilizando Spring Security y en el front React,no comprendo como manejar la seguridad, debido a que para usar react( desde el visual) ingreso desde otro puerto , y el ingreso desde ese puerto no se configurarlo para que siga las autorizaciones pertinentes! si alguien cuanta con material o podrá explicarme, estaré muy agradecido, saludos
aca adjunto la clase que me permite entrar desde otro servidor a los controladores

```
@Configuration
 public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
 @Override
 public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/api/v1/**") // Ruta donde quieres aplicar la configuración CORS
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:5173") // URL del frontend que tiene acceso 
    permitido
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE") // Métodos permitidos
            .allowCredentials(true); // Permitir el envío de credenciales (cookies, 
     autenticación, etc.)
     }
   }
```